# Knowing Hash Algorithm from Hashed String

Tags: hash

I found an application which stored its password in database as:

```
A69F00623BE6B8
```

It's a 14-character string length. How do I know this password algorithm? What's the keyword to describe this 14-character string length hashed value for Google?

7 bytes/56 bit hash algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a tool for identifying hashes if they are identifiable:
http://code.google.com/p/hash-identifier/

Comment: Just tried it on OP's hash and I got "Not Found", I tried upper and lowercases to be sure.  The list known/recognizable of hashes is here: http://code.google.com/p/hash-identifier/source/browse/trunk/Hash_ID_v1.1/Hash_ID.py#21

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to work out which hashing algorithm was used based on a single example digest. You can work out the digest length, and based on that make a guess, but it's only a guess. That's what the python script Mark mentions does.

I suspect that's not a string, by the way, but a hexadecimal number. Which would make it 56-bit.

Comment: Could it be DES? That's not a hash, of course, but your question doesn't give enough information to rule out that the password is encrypted rather than hashed...

Comment: I don't think so. DES has a **64 bit block size** and 56 bit key size. If it were encrypted with DES, it should have a size multiple of 64 bit.

Comment: D'oh, of course, that's a stupid mistake.